# Cómo detectar si paso una cierto tiempo y no se hizo click en ningún elemento?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de detectar que pase un tiempo determinado y si no hicieron click que se ejecute una función, como puedo hacerlo ? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberias poner un ejemplo mínimo de que intentaste hacerlo tu, no estamos para hacerte todo, sino para ayudarte con tu código, pero tratandose de que hoy es feriado en mi país y estoy aburrido, ahi va una posible solución:

```
<script>
  let clicks = 0;
  document.addEventListener('click', function(){
   clicks ++
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
   if(clicks === 0){
    console.log("No hiciste ningun click");
   }else {
    console.log("Has hecho " + clicks + " clicks.");
   }
  }, 3000);
 </script>
```

Te explico un poco de que se trata:

La instrucción document.addEventListener() pone al documento a la escucha de un click, sea donde sea que lo hagas dentro de la ventana del navegador.

Por otro lado inicio una variable para almacenar los clicks y dentro del listener le sumo 1 cada vez que se hace click.

Luego en el setTimeout, que es un temporizador, por asi decirlo, con un condicional determino si hubo o no clicks.

Por supuesto debes reemplazar a los console.log() por la funcion que quieras que se ejecute.

Espero te sea de utilidad!!

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta, perdón por no poner un ejemplo, es que no se me ocurría ningúno y no sabía por dónde empezar, muchas gracias